# How to change your default database type in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to know what is the code for default database type in Laravel.

```php
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')
```

Comment: [If the docs don't make it clear](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database), you probably have some specific problem or question.  Edit your question and be specific.

Answer (score 1):

[Change your .env](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#configuration) `DB_CONNECTION` variable to another type

For example for SQLite:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```